# some arrows do not appear

Tags: tikz-arrows

The following code produces two graphs and I wanted arrows everywhere, but only some edges are arrows, the other are normal edges.

I don't understand how it is even possible.
The arrow edges in the end are p1->p2, q2->q3 and q2'->q4

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[draw,circle]  
\node at (-1,-.5) {$H:$};
\node[vertex] (p1) at (0,0) {};
\node[vertex] (p2) at (0,-1) {};
\node[vertex] (p3) at (-1,-2) {};
\node[vertex] (p4) at (1,-2) {};
\draw[->] (p1) -- (p2);;
\draw[->] (p2) -- (p3);
\draw[->] (p2) -- (p4);
\node at (3.5,-.5) {$G:$};
\node[vertex] (q1) at (5,0) {};
\node[vertex] (q2) at (4,-1) {};
\node[vertex] (q2') at (6,-1) {};
\node[vertex] (q3) at (4,-2) {};
\node[vertex] (q4) at (6,-2) {};
\draw[->] (q1) -- (q2);
\draw[->] (q1) -- (q2');
\draw[->] (q2) -- (q3);
\draw[->] (q2') -- (q4);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for providing code. If you could complete it to make it compilable, that would be great.

Comment: Your code produces 2 graphs here: the 1st contains 3 arrows; the 2nd contains 4.

Comment: I get arrows everywhere, too, when I just add minimal code needed to compile. [Though this is a very inefficient way to draw trees.]

Comment: Maybe it is a zoom problem.

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Ti*k*Z has a [graph drawing library](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=363) which will make the drawing of these graphs significantly easier.

In the following example, the `baseline` key sets the vertical alignment of the graphs with the *H* and *G*.  With each node, the part before the slash `/` identifies the node uniquely so that it can be used again in the layout specification.  For example, you cold add another edge connecting nodes `3` and `4` in *H* by adding `3 -- 4,` in the graph specification.

The part in the quotes determines the label (or text) in the node.

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  graphs,
  graphdrawing,
}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\(H\):
\tikz [baseline=(2), >=stealth] \graph [tree layout, nodes={draw,circle}] {
  1/"" -> 2/"" -> {3/"", 4/""},
};
\(G\):
\tikz [baseline=(2), >=stealth] \graph [tree layout, nodes={draw,circle}] {
  1/"" -> {2/"" -> 3/"", 4/"" -> 5/""}, 
};
\end{document}
```

[image: output]